# Is there a way to boost volume on your machine from the standard volume?

Tags: xubuntu, volume-control

Hey everyone I am running Xubuntu 14.04 and I was wondering other than VLC media player is there a way to increase volume for Youtube, and system/games?  Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can increase the volume above 100%

Click on the speaker symbol   in the right corner --> go to **`sound settings`** and you should see a slider with which you can set your sound output above 100%

[image]

Comment: That information was very helpful!   Thank you!

Comment: @DesertGhost1776 :-) Nice to hear this, You are always welcome. If this answer did help you, please do not forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid !](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Severus' answer, you can also do this on a per-application basis (which you seem to allude to in your original question) by using the "playback" tab (see image below).

[image]

Comment: Is this Xubuntu 14.4 or Ubuntu?

Comment: It is Xubuntu 14.04